# Regular expression for Indian mobile numbers

Tags: regex

I want to find all the phone number's in a file, I need RegEx for this

valid formats:

```
+91 9916075509
+91-9916075509
+919916075509
9916075509
```

Also it should be able to take care of the space's before and after the phone number's most of the RegEx i found in google were not able to take care of the space.

I would appreciate if someone of you can help me out!

Answer (score 6):

I would use something like this:

```
^(\+91[\-\s]?)?[89]\d{9}$
```

Explanation:

```
^ - beginning of the string
   (\+91[\-\s]?)? - matches optional ISD code with optional - or whitespace inbetween
   [89]  - last I checked Indian mobile numbers begin with 8 or 9
   \d{9} - followed by 9 digits ( total of 10 )
$ - end of string
```

Comment: The above answer needs an edit, as some vendors in India support mobile numbers from 6 and 7 also which will need lead to a small change
    ^(\+91[\-\s]?)?[6789]\d{9}$ or 
    ^(\+91[\-\s]?)?\d{10}$ as we may have numbers from 4-5 too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I suppose:

```
[ ]*\+9(1[ -]?[0-9]{10}|9[0-9]{8})[ ]*
```

Answer (score 1):

via python

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = r'   +91 9916075509,+91-9916075509, +919916075509, 9916075509  '
>>> r = re.findall(r'(?:\+?\d{2}[ -]?)?\d{10}', txt)
>>> r
['+91 9916075509', '+91-9916075509', '+919916075509', '9916075509']
>>>
```

EDIT:

Here's another one that will handle arbitrary spacing and hyphens:

`(?:\+\s*\d{2}[\s-]*)?(?:\d[-\s]*){10}`

Accepts an optional leading `+` followed by 2 digits, then will match any continuous set of 10 digits separated by any amount of hyphens or whitespace.  The strings below are all valid examples.

```
000-000 0000
000-0 00-0 00-0
+00 0000000000
+00 000-000 0000
+00-000-000-0000
+ 00-000-0 00-0 00-0
```

I don't know anything about what other restrictions exist for Indian mobile numbers (e.g. must start with 9, etc.), but you should be able to change the regex to include those by substituting static digits in place of the `\d` placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this

```
/\+91-?[ \d]/
```

This will look for +91 with an optional -, followed by numbers or spaces.

As you are finding telephone numbers in a file I didn't want to make it too strict.

Add more to the character class in [] if you get any unwanted matches.